# Firebase .info/connected Android issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase states:

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

Problem: `.info/connected` says "not connected" even if internet is on after 60 seconds.

My active listener -->

```
keepConnected = database.getReference().child(“keep_open”);
   keepConnected.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           Log.v(TAG,snapshot.getValue().toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
   });
```

My info/connected listener -->

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      System.out.println("connected");
    } else {
      System.out.println("not connected");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

`Logs:
06-25 15:10:08.994 7572-7572/com.yourgesture.androidgesturecourier V/KEEPOPEN: 1529816684493
06-25 15:10:13.361 7572-7572/com.yourgesture.androidgesturecourier V/INTERNET: true
   ONLINE
06-25 15:11:03.803 7572-7572/com.yourgesture.androidgesturecourier V/INTERNET: false
   OFFLINE (edited)`

Comment: The code looks fine, but I'm not really sure I understand what happens. Can you describe it, or maybe show the sequence of logging output you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just the specific logs from the code above?

Comment: What is the output in your logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo logs edited in!

Comment: Where does the last two lines of code come from?

Comment: Its from .info/connected its a log instead of system.out

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any ideas friend?

Comment: Nope. I don't see what could be causing the disconnect. I'd also test if a change to the database still triggers the client after a few moments. If so, it might simply be something in the app (e.g. client code or SDK).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen @Daniel @Alex Mamo Greetings! I've tried the exact same example, as in the firebase presence page... It always goes inactive after 60 seconds! Gives me `V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`... even if I use keepSynced or an explicit eventListener... Can you please help!!!  D:

Comment: The client automatically disconnects if there are no active listeners and no writes for a minute, so that's probably what you're seeing. If you're only using Firebase for its presence system, attach a listener to a dummy node: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/ThisPathDoesNotExist");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ...` to trick the SDK into keeping the connection open. Note that Android might still close the connection though, which is beyond Firebase's control.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hello! I had actually done that after reading your very comment on some other SO question. Haha, after a few hours of debugging, I found out that there were two problems, one of which was my mistake! Namely, I forgot to clear access to the dummy reference in the security rules and secondly, [this fascinating issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47095855/6086782) regarding firebase timestamp offset validation in the security rules! Now, it's working swell! By the way, thanks for all your insightful comments and answers on SO regarding Firebase Mr. Frank, saved me many hours! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: @varun Hi, i facing the same issue, on 4G specially on Vodafone, I getting connection = false, and nothing working. How did you resolved it ?

Comment: @young_08 Oh, I did not face that problem. My phone's "inactivity disconnection" problem was solved after I fixed two issues in my code (see my above comment). Hmmmm, I think your problem must be your 4G connection, give it more time... Does it fail even on Wi-fi connection?

Comment: @varun No, Its working fine with the WIFI and all other Mobile Network except Vodafone.